# How to permute string with a number?

Tags: c++, string, combinations

Lets say i've char 'A' and 'B' for each character i need to add it with all numbers...

```
               ""
         /            \   
      "A"             "B"
    /  |  \        /  |  \
   /   |   \      /   |   \
"A1" "A2" "A3"  "B1" "B2" "B3"
```

how to do it?

i tried but i didn't get the correct recursive idea.

generally i've set of chars [A,B,C,...z] each is permuted with other set of numbers [0,...9]

Recursively how to solve answers? [or Backtracking?] i can't get ideas. how to approach problems and solve it?

or simply keeping it we have an  array[]={A,D}
we have offset [0,1,2]

we need to permute the string with array of chars but also adding offsets

```
A-- D+0   AD
A-- D+1   AE
A-- D+2   AF
B...D+0   BD
B...D+1   BE
B...D+2   BF
```

this is for just 2 characters.

Comment: i can't get ideas on what you are trying to do **either**.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you'd like to produce for a specific set of characters and numbers, i.e. [A,B,C] and [1,2,3]?

Comment: Why not CD, CE and CF?

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two sets.(your number and characters). use char arrays for holding the input and output sets,

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve it recursively for each offset.

```
fun(int offset,int i){
  if(offset==0)
     then print the array

  for(;i<n;i++){
    a[i]++;
    fun(offset-1,i+1);
    a[i]--;
  }
}
```

Here 'n' is length of the array `a` with given characters. A pseudo code which prints all possible arrays for each offset. You have to call the above array for each offset.